# How to pass on a Request received by JMeter workbench to a Test Plan

Tags: xml, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

My JMeter Script resides in between 2 webservices. The first service post's and xml to JMeter and I want JMeter to Assert the xml using a response assertion. Then I have to pass on, only the assertion passed xml's to the test plan to hit the second service.

I have Jmeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder Listening on a specific port, It captures the request xml. Now i want to pass the captured xml to the test plan so that the xml can be used in a rest/soap Request.

How do I pass the xml captured in a workbench to a test plan?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to:

1. Move recorded request to the test plan
2. Apply Assertion of your choice to it
3. Add an [If Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) after the request from point 1
4. Put the following condition into the If Controller: `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}`
5. Add request to 2nd service as a child of the If Controller